# How to rotate an object in Blender 2.74 using python script

Tags: python, scripting, objects, transforms

I wanna rotate an object with this code below:

```
import bpy
from math import *
import mathutils

Name = 'Dimi'
me = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 0.5, depth = 1)
scj = bpy.context.scene
me1 = bpy.context.object.data
ob = bpy.data.objects.new(Name, me1)
scj.objects.link(ob)
for ob in scj.objects:
    ob.location.x += 4
    ob.location.y += 0
    ob.location.z += 0

me.transform(ob.matrix)
ob.RotY = 0
ob.RotX = 0
```

But this function

```
me.transform(ob.matrix)
ob.RotY = 0
ob.RotX = 0
```

is from blender 2.49 and can't find how to do this in a 2.74 version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import bpy
from math import *  # It's considered bad practice to import everything from a library, especially when you're not using any (or just a few) of its function
import mathutils

Name = 'Dimi'

# The primitive_cylinder_add does not return the object, but rather only a status indicating success or failure
exitStatus = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 0.5, depth = 1)
scj = bpy.context.scene

# The added cylinder will be the active object afterits created
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
ob.name = Name

# These two lines are unnecessary and will generate another copy of your cylinder
#ob = bpy.data.objects.new(Name, me1)
#scj.objects.link(ob)

# If you want to move your object, simply set its location thus:
ob.location = ( 4, 0, 0 )

# And you can rotate the object the same way
ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)  # Note that you need to use radians rather than angles here
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you want something akin to,

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Vector

context = bpy.context
Name = 'Dimi'
# operators don't return object refs.
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 0.5, depth = 1)

scene = context.scene
ob = scene.objects.active # the newly added cylinder.
ob.name = Name
# move the object
ob.location += Vector((4, 0, 0))
# set the objects rotation
ob.rotation_euler = (0, 0, radians(20))
```

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive..add returns an object when run in object mode, or adds that primitive to a mesh when run in edit mode.  Did you really want to move all objects in the scene?

Comment: is there something like radians but for XYZ scaling? or how do I properly change scales of XYZ

Comment: you can use something like bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(3, .5, 2)) for scaling